# Remove all zeros from array O(n), no extra memory

Tags: algorithm

COuld you suggest me the best algorithm to remove all zeros from given array in O(n) time and without external memory.
For example, 1 2 0 0 3 2 0 2 becomes 1 2 3 2 2

Comment: loop, remember write position..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use two pointers - one for read and one for write.

- Iterate with the reader pointer on the array - if the element is zero increase only it.
- If the element is not zero - write it and increase both pointers.

Comment: Brilliant, but @amit i believe it will modify the array to make it 1 2 3 2 2 2 0 2 and not 1 2 3 2 2. One more step please :)

Comment: @D34dman The "next step" is going to be language dependent. In C  you could use `realloc()` to shrink the array, in languages with dynamic arrays (like java's `ArrayList` you can remove the tail), or (again in C) you just might want to change the variable `n` that indicates the length of your array.